# How to display data from two SQL tables in one GridView in Web Forms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms, sql-server-express

In my SQL Server Express I have `Recipients`, `MailingLists` and `RecipientMailingList` (`Recipient`'s ID and `MailingList`'s ID) tables. Each recipient is assigned to a few mailing lists. I want to display all recipients' info in a `GridView`. I wanted to this by dragging and dropping the table from Server Explorer to the `.aspx` source code. However, what I got is a `GridView` without any information on `MailingLists` as those are in other tables.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="RecipientID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" EmptyDataText="There are no data records to display.">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="RecipientID" HeaderText="Recipient ID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="RecipientID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="First Name" SortExpression="FirstName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="Last Name" SortExpression="LastName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" SortExpression="City" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="Email" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Phone" HeaderText="Phone" SortExpression="Phone" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="MailingLists" HeaderText="Mailing Lists" SortExpression="MailingLists" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NewsletterConnectionString1 %>" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Recipients] WHERE [RecipientID] = @RecipientID" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Recipients] ([FirstName], [LastName], [City], [Email], [Phone]) VALUES (@FirstName, @LastName, @City, @Email, @Phone)" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NewsletterConnectionString1.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [RecipientID], [FirstName], [LastName], [City], [Email], [Phone] FROM [Recipients]" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Recipients] SET [FirstName] = @FirstName, [LastName] = @LastName, [City] = @City, [Email] = @Email, [Phone] = @Phone WHERE [RecipientID] = @RecipientID">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="RecipientID" Type="Int32" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="FirstName" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="LastName" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="City" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Email" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Phone" Type="String" />
        </InsertParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="FirstName" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="LastName" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="City" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Email" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Phone" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="RecipientID" Type="Int32" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

How can I create a `GridView` (or possible ListView) containing all the information from those three tables (recipient's details with mailing lists' names)?

UPDATE:
I have such a query to use as data-source:

```
SELECT Recipients.RecipientID, Recipients.FirstName, Recipients.LastName, 
Recipients.City, Recipients.Email, Recipients.Phone, MailingLists.Name
FROM Recipients
INNER JOIN RecipientMailingList
ON Recipients.RecipientID = RecipientMailingList.Recipient_RecipientID
INNER JOIN MailingLists ON RecipientMailingList.MailingList_MailingListID = MailingLists.MailingListID
```

However, what I get is a different row for the same user with multiple mailing lists. The result I expect is to have one row for each user with a column of comma-separated `MailingLists`.

Comment: Do you have a Select Query that has your Join Statements..?

Comment: just use sql to populate your data source

Comment: I updated the question with necessary details.

Answer (score 0):

you can use templatefield and call your function.

```
                <ItemTemplate>
             <%#GetName(Convert.ToInt32(Eval("RecipientsID"))) %>
         </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
```

Now you have to write a function in your cs file that get int value and returns string.